# How do I change "Image" tab information on a downloaded icon (PNG)?

Tags: command-line, image-processing, metadata, png

I downloaded an icon, [jester.png](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/jester_329617) from [FlatIcon.com](https://www.flaticon.com/). The website states that if you download without a paid membership, you must credit the author, which in this case is [Freepik](http://www.freepik.com). In fact, here is what they say you must include in your credit:

```
<div>Icons made by <a href="http://www.freepik.com" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a></div>
```

So basically, you include the author (FreePik), the site it came from (FlatIcon), and the license (CC 3.0 BY).

Now, when I right-click on the icon jester.png in Nautilus (in **Ubuntu 14.04**) and select Properties, I see four tabs: **Basic**, **Permissions**, **Open With**, and **Image**. Look at the **Image** tab:

[image: screenshot of Image tab with Image Type, Width, Height, and Created By fields]

What I would like to do is change the string in the **Created By** field from `www.inskpace.org` to `www.freepik.com, from www.flaticon.com, CC 3.0 BY`.

It is not clear to me how to do this in Ubuntu 14.04. Other questions have dealt with changing permissions and ownership by command line, but none of these cover the fields of the Image tab. Furthermore, it would be nice to know how to do this both by command line and within Unity, but one or the other would suffice. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Installed and used exiv2 as requested. Here is the output:

```
$ exiv2 /home/gracious1/Pictures/Jesters/jester_yellow-face-256px.png
File name       : /home/gracious1/Pictures/Jesters/jester_yellow-face-256px.png
File size       : 13078 Bytes
MIME type       : image/png
Image size      : 256 x 256
/home/gracious1/Pictures/Jesters/jester_yellow-face-256px.png: No Exif data found in the file
```

Comment: I am not sure which field is displayed here, could you install the tool `exiv2` (`sudo apt install exiv2`) and show which key is corresponding to your "Created by" value in the output of `exiv2 -pt /PATH/TO/YOUR/IMAGE.PNG`?

Comment: @ByteCommander OK, done. Original post edited. Not sure it was helpful, no Exif data.

Comment: If they ask you to mention this explicitly in your website, then I don't think hiding it away in the image metadata will be enough. Just saying.

Comment: @muru For now, not using it in a website. Using it for my own purposes on my desktop (making a custom icon that opens a particular profile of a browser). If I do use it on a website, then of course I'll add the code. But that doesn't solve the issue of "*Where* is that **Created By** string coming from?"

Comment: @gracious1 it's from the software that created the image.

Comment: @muru So where is it that I can modify it? That's the point of my question (as explicitly asked in post). I want to modify that.

Comment: I asked for the `exiv2 -pt FILENAME.PNG` output. Note the "-pt".

Comment: @gracious1 most editors don't give an option for that, since the field identifies them. You can set the author (different from "created by") and license information in various editors, like gimp or Inkscape, though.

Comment: @ByteCommander Oops. When I do `exiv2 -pt` instead of just `exiv2` I get no output at all, just returns to the $ prompt.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `exiv2 pt` instead of `exiv2 -pt`? But I'm not sure that `exiv2` is the best tool for this job anyway, see my answer below. Judging from a short search, PNG has its own metadata that are not part of Exif. But those metadata have been standardized as a version of XMP about a year ago. Far from sure about the details, but it seems to be something along that line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text for "Created by" is taken from the image's metadata, more specifically, from the metadata key `Software`. There are a number of standards and formats to embed metadata in an image, among them Exif, IPTC/IIM or XMP.

I'm not sure why `exiv2` doesn't find the metadata of that image, but I've found that `exiftool` (from package `libimage-exiftool-perl`) does. You can extract the current value of the field with

```
exiftool -Software path/to/file
```

and set a new value with

```
exiftool -Software="new value for field" path/to/file
```

Comment: That worked! It also created a backup of the unmodified file.

Comment: @gracious1 Though IMO you should change the Author/License fields and not the "Created By" field.

Comment: @muru That is a good point. OK, what is the command to do that?

Comment: @gracious1 same as this answer, but with `-Author` and `-License` instead of `-Software`.